# File not created when running a task locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a task that is to output a CSV. I can confirm that the CSV is in memory but when I call the following, the file is not created

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', file_name), 'w') do |file|
        file.write(csv_export)
      end
```

I think it might be a permissions issue because the task is running in the application context but for the life of me can not discover what the user name is to add to tmp folder permission

Comment: It's just your username on your computer, if you're just running Rails from the terminal without any dockers or special configs.

Comment: Try running the code from the terminal, you must see some error messages. `File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp/test.txt'), 'w') { |file| file.write('test') }`

Answer (score 1):

you could check the current permission of that tmp folder (`readable?`, `writable?`, `executable?`), you could also check whether the permission requester is the folder owner or group owner with (`owned?`, `grpowned?`), then you could grant the permission for tmp folder by `chmod` to create `file_name`

```rb
tmp_folder = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp')
if File.owned?(tmp_folder) && !File.executable?(tmp_folder)
 File.chmod(0700, tmp_folder)
end

File.open(File.join(tmp_folder,file_name), 'w') do |file|
  file.write(csv_export)
end
```